# Find similar numbers - array inconsistency

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, counting, function-definition

I'm trying to solve a simple beginner exercise, I compare two arrays and find the numbers that appear in both. The result is put into another array called result. For whatever reason the result should contain "2 44 55" but it shows "2 1 10 10". What did I do wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

void common_elements(int array_1[], int array_2[]){
    int result[] {0};
    int counter{0};
    
    for (int i{0}; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j{0}; j < 10; j++){  
            if (array_2[i] == array_1[j]){
                result[counter] = array_1[j];
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        std::cout << "There are 0 common elements";
    } else {
        std::cout << "There are " << counter << " common elements they are : ";
        for (int k{0}; k < counter; k++){
            std::cout << result[k] << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int data1[] {1,2,4,5,9,3,6,7,44,55}; 
    int data2[] {11,2,44,45,49,43,46,47,55,88};
    common_elements(data1,data2);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused because when I std::cout the numbers during examination (two nested loops), the result is correct.

Comment: Ask yourself, how big is `int result[] {0};`?  How many elements does it allow to be stored in it?

Comment: Ask the compiler to help you out: https://godbolt.org/z/a5Wbbrjvj . The command line arguments `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ask for extra diagnostic messages `-O3` says optimize heavily. This forces the compiler to look more closely at the code, and the closer look often spots more mistakes. `-g` says gimme debug info. `-fsanitize=address,undefined` instructs the compiler to build in extra runtime checking for a wide variety of mistakes. The options will work for recent releases of GCC and clang are significantly different with Visual studio.

Comment: What it tells you is on line ten, the index went out of bounds for `result`. `int result[] {0};` asks for and receives an array of size 1. The size cannot be changed after the variable is created, so anything other than an index value of 0 is invalid.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.   Attempting to store more than one value into an array with only one element.   If you want a container that can dynamically grow to accommodate an arbitrary number of elements, use something like `std::vector`.   Even with a `std::vector`, you still need to ensure there is a correct number of elements BEFORE accessing/modifying an element, so read the documentation rather than just assuming it will behave as needed.

Comment: @Calimero Correct.  Arrays have a fixed size in C++ and your array is not big enough to store the number of elements you are trying to store in it, giving you undefined behavior.

Comment: @user20716902 Pretty sure they mean that the element with the value of `2` is the only one that is valid, not the index of 2 is the only one that is valid.

Answer (score 0):

It is just containing one single element, because the compiler deduces the length to 1. This would mean the 2 is valid, all other values are "out of bound". Thanks for your help. I repaired it to

```
int result[10]{0};
```

Now it's working, thanks a lot.
Btw: It is a C++ course but it starts from the very beginning. That why this looks like C.

Comment: "Btw: It is a C++ course but it starts from the very beginning. That why this looks like C." yes exactly thats the problem. [They should stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk). C++ is C++ from the beginning

Comment: I really recommend the talk. Its one of the best I know :)

Comment: Just about everyone who has used C++ in the wild, as in not just in academia, quickly comes to the conclusion that C++ is almost always taught backward. I've lost count of the number of young programmers I've met who complained about C++ being much harder than Python/java/whatever for simple tasks until they're shown how to use C++ 
 to do those simple tasks correctly.

Comment: @user4581301 not only they do not show you the right way, but they teach you the wrong way so well that it can be extremely difficult to unlearn it. I still remember how I though that `std::vector` would be inferior to c-arrays in so many ways, it was all just brainwash.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm pretty sure a chunk of the `vector` problem is few are ever taught to turn on the optimizer because the emphasis is on writing superfast, hand-tuned code. They test the speed of `vector`, are utterly horrified, and swear off the use of it forever. Once solved the bulk of a tech start-up's software performance problems by adding a couple `-02`s to a makefile. Smart gang. Wrote smart code. Didn't know how to use the tools worth a damn.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
std::vector<int> common_elements( const int array_1[], size_t n1, 
                                  const int array_2[], size_t n2 );
```

Using the magic number `10` within the function as

```
for (int i{0}; i < 10; i++){
```

does not make sense. The function can be called for arrays that have different numbers of elements.

This declaration of an array

```
int result[] {0};
```

declares an array with only one element that also does not make sense.

Also the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to output a message. The function should return a sequence of common elements of two arrays.

The function can be defined the following way

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

//...

std::vector<int> common_elements( const int array_1[], size_t n1, 
                                  const int array_2[], size_t n2 )
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    if ( n1 != 0 && n2 != 0 )
    {
        if ( n2 < n1 )
        {
            std::swap( n1, n2 );
            std::swap( array_1, array_2 );
        } 
  
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
        {
            size_t count = 1;
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
            {
                if ( array_1[j] == array_1[i] ) ++count;
            }

            for ( size_t j = 0; count != 0 && j < n2; j++ )
            {
                if ( array_2[j] == array_1[i] )
                {
                    --count;
                }
            }

            if ( count == 0 ) v.push_back( array_1[i] );
        }
    }
  
    return v;
}
```

And in main the function is called like

```
int data1[] {1,2,4,5,9,3,6,7,44,55}; 
int data2[] {11,2,44,45,49,43,46,47,55,88};

auto v = common_elements( data1, std::size( data1 ), data2, std::size( data2 ) );

if ( std::size( v ) == 0 ) 
{
    std::cout << "There are 0 common elements";
} 
else 
{
    std::cout << "There are " << std::size( v ) << " common elements they are : ";
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Instead of the vector you could use `std::map<intg, size_t>`. In this case the container will contain how many times a common number is encountered in the both arrays.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

std::vector<int> common_elements( const int array_1[], size_t n1,
    const int array_2[], size_t n2 )
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    if (n1 != 0 && n2 != 0)
    {
        if (n2 < n1)
        {
            std::swap( n1, n2 );
            std::swap( array_1, array_2 );
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        {
            size_t count = 1;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (array_1[j] == array_1[i]) ++count;
            }

            for (size_t j = 0; count != 0 && j < n2; j++)
            {
                if (array_2[j] == array_1[i])
                {
                    --count;
                }
            }

            if (count == 0) v.push_back( array_1[i] );
        }
    }

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    int data1[]{ 1,2,4,5,9,3,6,7,44,55 };
    int data2[]{ 11,2,44,45,49,43,46,47,55,88 };

    auto v = common_elements( data1, std::size( data1 ), data2, std::size( data2 ) );

    if (std::size( v ) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "There are 0 common elements";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There are " << std::size( v ) << " common elements they are : ";
        for (const auto &item : v)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
There are 3 common elements they are : 2 44 55
```